# how do I start nvim in search mode? (I do not want to execute a search, merely for nvim to be ready to accept a search string)

Tags: neovim

I would like to open a file and have nvim automatically be in search mode once the file is opened.

I need to find the correct command to use, probably in the form of nvim -c `Command` file.txt

To clarify, I want to start nvim and be able to start searching by typing in my search string without first pressing '/' to enter search mode.

running nvim -c '/searchString' executes the search immediately and is not what I want

My use case is that I use nvim as a scrollback pager for kitty.

```
# kitty passes text to nvim via stdinput which i write to a tmp file in /tmp/kitty_scrollback_buffer
# I then open this file with the nvim terminal by catting the file
# is there anyway to then automatically enter command search mode so that nvim is ready to search when i enter a search string (I do not want to type /, i want to be able to search immediately)
exec nvim \
    -u NONE \
    -c "silent! write! /tmp/kitty_scrollback_buffer | terminal cat /tmp/kitty_scrollback_buffer - " \
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right there. If you want to search `foo` in `file.txt`, run this:

```bash
nvim -c "/foo" file.txt
```

Comment: ah sorry, I should have been more explicit. I understand that /foo searches for foo immediately, I was wondering if it's possible to enter search mode without executing a search.... eg something like `nvim -c "/"` (unfortunately, I believe the -c syntax always executes the command, while I would prefer not to execute the command as I do not want to exit search mode)

Answer (score 0):

The command `nvim -c <cmd>` executes  after the configuration, and when used with a file, such as in `nvim -c '/foo' file.txt`, it performs the search immediately, which is not useful in this case.

To emulate sending keystrokes to nvim, the following command works well:

```
nvim -c ‘call feedkeys(”/”)’
```

If you are using [kitty-scrollback.nvim](https://github.com/mikesmithgh/kitty-scrollback.nvim), you can configure it in `~/.config/kitty/kity.conf` as shown below:

```
map ctrl+shift+h kitty_scrollback_nvim –nvim-args -c ‘call feedkeys(”?”)’
```

Using `?` as the keystroke means to start the search backward.

Hope that helps.